# Error handling XBAP when certificate is not in Trusted Publishers

Tags: c#, deployment, error-handling, clickonce, xbap

I have an XBAP that requires full trust, and my certificate to be located in the Trusted Publishers store.

How can I gracefully handle the situation where the certificate is not located in the trusted publishers store?   As it stands now, click once will display a very ugly error message.

I would like to avoid that error, and replace it with instructions for users who don't have that certificate installed.

Comment: For now I've created *another* ClickOnce application that just installs the certificate in trusted publishers - and I give users a link to that (this app is NOT an xbap and therefore doesn't have the same problem)